# mpdf: problem with permission of temp files

Tags: mpdf

I don't understand why mPDF creates temp files using 600 as permissions.

I have a problem with Laravel because sometimes we create PDF using jobs, and sometime from webpage

If job run first, files are created as user:user with 600 as permission. So when www-data runs cannot read the files and it explodes. We added sticky bit to tmp folder so new file are created as user:www-data, but this is not enough, because of 600 as permissions.

Otherwise if web run first, files are created as www-data:www-data with 600 as permission. When a job run, it cannot read the files, because it's running as user. And it explodes.

At every deploy, we must manually run a creation of a PDF, change ownership to user:www-data and permissions to 664.

Is there a way to ask mPDF to create files as 664 instead of 600 !?

So at every update we do a manual run, and manually change

Comment: I don't really understand the reasoning of creating a StackOverflow question AND GitHub issue almost simultaneously (especially when this is a valid bug/feature request). This has been solved in codebase, I suggest this question can be deleted/closed.

Comment: I close this.
Normally, there is no chance that a bug request is approved; normally it's closed, ignored, etc... So I was asking here, because probably there was a configuration I didn't know to workaround this issue. 
Anyway, SO is becoming every day a less fair place

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is a valid bug report and has been fixed in codebase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved in the code.

From >= 8.0.11, files are being created with 664 permission.